# Calling an external function from within socket.on()

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am using sockets and need to call an external function from within my socket middle-ware file.

I have the following routes.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const baskets = {};

module.exports = function(app, socketio) {
  const logBasketID = basketID => {
    console.log("this works" + basketID);
  };

  const addToBasket = (basketID, fruit) => {
    var basket = baskets[basketID];
    basket.fruit.push({
      fruit
    });
    return basket;
  };

  app.post("/fruit/add", (req, res) => {
    const fruit = req.body.fruit;
    const basketID = req.body.basketID;
    addToBasket(basketId, fruit);
    res.status(200).send(basket);
  });
};
```

I am trying to invoke the logBasketID method from within my sockets.io middleware file when a message is received from client.
My io file looks like this:

```
initialize = function(io) {
  io.sockets.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("user connected");

    socket.on("join", (roomId, callback) => {
      socket.join(gameId);
      console.log("user joined room: " + roomId);
    });

    socket.on("logBasketID", (basketId, callback) => {
      console.log("user requested to remove fruit: " + basketId);
      //here I want to call a function from fruitRoutes.js like
      // logBasketID(basketId)
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("user disconnected");
    });
  });
};

module.exports = {
  initialize
};
```

I have tried to require the routes file in the socket file using:

```
var Routes= require("../routes/fruitRoutes")
```

and then callling `Routes.logBasketID(basketID)` but I still get an error.

Is there a way to call this external function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're messing things a little.
Please, read more about express [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), and about [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) (especially Single responsibility principle).

Logically, it would be better to remove code for socket into separate file to not to mess it with express routes.

Your express `app.js` (or any other file, where your server starts), should contain import of route file, and then use it in code like this:

```
const mainRoutes = require('/path/to/routes/file');
const express = require('express);
const app = express();

mainRoutes(app);
```

File with socket methods should be separate:

```
// socket-methods.js
const logBasketID = basketID => { console.log("this works" + basketID) };

module.exports = { logBasketID }
```

And then, in `initialize` file:

```
const { logBasketID } = require('/path/to/socket-methods.js');
```